# formik onChange working not asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, validation, asynchronous, onchange, formik

```
  name: Yup.string()
    .required(),
});

  const {
    errors,
    touched,
    getFieldProps,
    handleChange,
  } = formik;


  function onChange(e) {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      **(HERE I HAVE errors.length 0, despite this my input is empty and is required, so I shuld have errors here. I have error here, but with delay, )**
      dispatch(setInvitationConfigParam({ name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value }));
    }
    handleChange(e);
  }

<InputWrapper>
  <TextInput
   customClass="input"
   error={false}
   textFieldProps={{
   label: t('configurationForm.settings.nameConfiguration'),
   error: hasErrors('name', errors, touched),
   helperText: getErrors('name', errors, touched),
   ...getFieldProps('name'),
   onChange,
}}
tooltipTitle={t('configurationForm.settings.nameConfigurationDescription')}
/>
```

What I want and why I have problem.

I want to sending dispach function every time when user change his input name, but if the input name is empty I didn't want sendig dispatch.

The problem is that: object `errors` show errors with a delay.
how can I have `errors` with no dealy?